# How to fetch facebook user friends email ids in ios

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

m using facebook graph apis in my app.
i want to fetch my fb friends email ids
in a tableview in my app
fb graph user doesn't provides any property for emails.
how can i achive this
help me
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    self.userInfoTextView.hidden = NO;

```
// Fetch user data
[FBRequestConnection
 startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                   id<FBGraphUser> user,
                                   NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         NSString *userInfo = @"";

         // Example: typed access (name)
         // - no special permissions required
         userInfo = [userInfo
                     stringByAppendingString:
                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@\n\n",
                      user.name]];

         // Example: typed access, (birthday)
         // - requires user_birthday permission
         userInfo = [userInfo
                     stringByAppendingString:
                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Birthday: %@\n\n",
                      user.birthday]];

         // Example: partially typed access, to location field,
         // name key (location)
         // - requires user_location permission
         userInfo = [userInfo
                     stringByAppendingString:
                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %@\n\n",
                      user.location[@"name"]]];



         // Example: access via key (locale)
         // - no special permissions required
         userInfo = [userInfo
                     stringByAppendingString:
                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Locale: %@\n\n",
                      user[@"locale"]]];


         // Example: access via key for array (languages)
         // - requires user_likes permission
         if (user[@"languages"]) {
             NSArray *languages = user[@"languages"];
             NSMutableArray *languageNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             for (int i = 0; i < [languages count]; i++) {
                 languageNames[i] = languages[i][@"name"];
             }
             userInfo = [userInfo
                         stringByAppendingString:
                         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Languages: %@\n\n",
                          languageNames]];
         }
                      // Display the user info
         self.userInfoTextView.text = userInfo;
     }
 }];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your code. Hope it will be helpful to you.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot obtain e-mail addresses for friends through the Facebook API (with good reason - to prevent spam). You can obtain the current user's e-mail address, but only with an extended permission ([more about that here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/)).

Comment: thanks  for ur answer...gave me lot of relief..dont have to search anymore